# Make Active Admin escape filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is it possible to have active admin escape characters such as `_` when placed in a filter in order to have them behave like plain text rather than a wildcard?

For example if I was filtering on email addresses and one user had the address `bob_anderson@whatever.com` and another had the address `bobkanderson@whatever.com` and the user searched for `bob_anderson` I would like only the former to be returned. Currently both are returned because the underscore is interpreted as a wildcard.